# How to prevent a VSTO Office Add-In from automatically getting disabled?

Tags: outlook-addin

We run some custom add-ins in Outlook application and occasionally find that the Outlook application disables them; I then have to manually go to the application settings and re-enable them on each users PC. We are running Microsoft Office 365 click to run applications. I have tried the following but nothing seem to work 100% of the time.

I have tried setting the "AddinList/ProgID" REG key to 1 (always enabled) as described here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/support-for-keeping-add-ins-enabled.

I have also tried setting a number of registry key combinations as described here - https://www.konnectemail.com/prevent-outlook-add-in-from-getting-disabled

Is there a specific way to tell the office application to NEVER disable a particular add-in regardless of the Office version?